# Can one refer to pieces of proteins produced by enzymatic digestion as "enzymatic lysates"?

Tags: proteins, terminology, pharmacology, translation

A Russian text I'm translating says this:

> The location of post-translational modification (PTM) sites was determined using the “bottom-up” approach commonly used in this field. In accordance with this approach, **enzymatic lysates** from each of the studied MAB batches were separated using a reversed-phase chromatography column at high pressure (UHPLC), and peptide maps were plotted.

Can one refer to pieces of proteins produced by enzymatic digestion as enzymatic **lysates**? Or will **lysates** always imply that a biological cell has been destroyed?

The text I'm translating does not refer to cells being destroyed. The proteins in question are monoclonal antibodies present in drugs (solutions, tablets), therefore no cell destruction is involved.

I'm unsure whether to retain this word, "lysates", or use "digests" instead.

Here's an excerpt from the original Russian text:

> Идентификация положений РТМ проводилось по общепринятому в отрасли подходу «снизу-вверх». В соответствии с этим подходом, **ферментативные лизаты** каждой исследуемой серии МАТ разделяли на обращенно-фазовой хроматографической колонке при высоком давление (УВЭЖХ) с получением пептидных карт.

Comment: Digests would ok or maybe hydrolysates. Incidentally for monoclonal antibodies I think mAb, not MAB, is probably standard usage.